# Combining multiple rows into single column

Tags: mysql

The return from my MySQL statement displays an example below:

```
id 1 | status | id 2 | name | category
001  | open   | 011  | john | person
001  | open   | 011  | john | male
```

How would I combine the multiple rows to the category column? Like the example below.

```
id 1 | status | id 2 | name | category
001  | open   | 011  | john | person, male
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is what you need

```
CREATE TABLE customers
    ([id 1] int, [status] varchar(4), [id 2] int, [name] varchar(4), [category] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO customers
    ([id 1], [status], [id 2], [name], [category])
VALUES
    (001, 'open', 011, 'john', 'person'),
    (001, 'open', 011, 'john', 'male')
;
select * from dbo.customers
```

---- You have to use `STUFF` function with `FOR XML PATH`

```
 select distinct cs.[id 1]
    ,cs.[status]
    ,cs.[id 2]
    ,cs.[name]
    ,stuff((
            select ',' + c.[category]
            from dbo.customers c
            where cs.[id 1] = c.[id 1]
            for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') as [category]
     from dbo.customers cs
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am using MySQL. So I have tried to use the equivalent GROUP_CONCAT. By using GROUP_CONCAT it concatenates the category column but reduces my 500 results into a single row.

Answer (score 2):

In Mysql query should be like

```
select `id 1`,`status`,`id 2`,`name`,group_concat( category order by `id 1` asc SEPARATOR ',') as category 
from customer;
```

Comment: Makes my query 20% longer....Thanks a lot hahaha.  However, it does the job.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GROUP_CONCAT and then GROUP_BY your id.

```
SELECT t.id1, t.status, t.id2, t.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.category) category
FROM yourtable t
WHERE (t.name = 'john' or t.name = 'othername')
GROUP BY t.id1
```

Answer (score 0):

The query:

```
SELECT t.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.search_text) category 
FROM tblusersearches t 
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

works perfectly.